# Different execution plan for the same query with higher OFFSET

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am facing a problem with a `select` from database. I am calling the same query in a loop and changing only `offset`. First 9 queries are so fast (like 300ms), but the 10th and following queries take around 40s.

I print to my postgresql logs as much logs as I could and I saw two things:

1. After this log:

   ```
   2024-03-20 21:20:00 2024-03-20 20:20:00.105 UTC [34] LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:15:37.444 user=admin database=registry host=172.20.0.1 port=46436`
   ```

   database again works properly, calls 9 queries so fast and then slows again - to time when it disconnect again. Making a breakpoint in code and restarting database also helped, but it's not a solution. Also when I call something like this when I stay on breakpoint:

   ```sql
   SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
   FROM pg_stat_activity
   WHERE datname = 'your_database_name';
   ```

   helps to pass next 9 queries without lags, but like before - it's not a solution.
2. When queries slow down I see different execution plans than I saw when they were fast. These are the differences that I saw:

   - Slower query has better execution cost
   - Queries has another operations or operations order
   - Slower query has parameters (like $1, $2, etc.) instead of values which appears in queries which are called fast

Here's the link to diff: https://www.diffchecker.com/vYu3Ejrp/

I also tried:

- changing postgres properties (resources like memory, etc.)
- changing max connections pool in hikari
- disabling hibernate cache
- and more things that I probably don't remember now

When I use queries with less complexity (for example: I remove one `where` or `join` clause), it works perfectly and I can call in loop as many queries as I want. Also when I add some indexes problem dissappears. But for me this is so strange. I guess that if it is efficiency problem then DB should answer always slowly, not after few queries. Am I right?

---

To summarize this I can add that

- When I use `entityManager.createNativeQuery()` instead of `entityManager.createQuery()` and making it with criteria builder, everything works fine.
- When I call this query trhough a script in dbeaver (2000 times in loop) it's fine.
- When I pass this query with Python it works fine.

But from logs I see that problem is that DB executes query so long.

Comment: Probably a problem of transaction. But we do not have the code...

Comment: The fact that adding indexes resolves the problem indicates that database performance is indeed a factor. The differences in execution plans between fast and slow queries suggest that PostgreSQL might choose different plans based on statistics, workload, or parameter values.  Run ANALYZE on your tables to ensure that PostgreSQL has the latest data distribution information. Also, consider running VACUUM to clean up dead tuples and improve query performance.

Comment: I just realized that my query don't slow when I use 
`plan_cache_mode=force_custom_plan`
but it slows at 1st query when I use:
`plan_cache_mode=force_generic_plan`

Answer (score 1):

> I guess that if it is efficiency problem then DB should answer always slowly, not after few queries

The documentation of the [`PREPARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) statement says:

> A prepared statement can be executed with either a generic plan or a custom plan. ... The current rule for this is that the first five executions are done with custom plans and the average estimated cost of those plans is calculated. Then a generic plan is created and its estimated cost is compared to the average custom-plan cost. Subsequent executions use the generic plan if its cost is not so much higher than the average custom-plan cost as to make repeated replanning seem preferable.

This explains why your execution plan changes after *some* executions (not sure how you comes to the *nine* executions) and why it is stable if you force `plan_cache_mode`.

The root cause is that the *generic plan* (i.e. the plan using variables instaed of literals) has wrong cost (too low) so after the switch the performance degradate:

```
custom query plan -  Limit  (cost=6337.58..6579.13 rows=1 width=1174)
generic query plan - Limit  (cost=1808.72..2881.01 rows=1 width=1174)
```

To see why PostgreSQL produce such difference you must investigate the differencies between the two execution plans. A *starting point* is the most nested access estimation that produces similar cost, but **two orders of magnitude different row count** - `rows=11761` for the predicated with *literals* vs. `70` using *bind variables*...

```
->  Seq Scan on schema_registry.value_items vi1_0  (cost=0.00..695.64 rows=11761 width=700)
      Output: vi1_0.id, vi1_0.created_at, vi1_0.last_modified_at, vi1_0.serial_id, vi1_0.version, vi1_0.deleted, vi1_0.fields, vi1_0.description, vi1_0.group_key, vi1_0.key, vi1_0.language, vi1_0.status, vi1_0.translation, vi1_0.translation_extended, vi1_0.type
      Filter: (((NOT vi1_0.deleted) OR (vi1_0.deleted IS NULL)) AND ((vi1_0.key)::text ~~ 'KATALOG_USLUG_TESTOWY_2%'::text) AND (((vi1_0.language)::text = 'PL'::text) OR ((vi1_0.language)::text = 'ALL'::text) OR (vi1_0.language IS NULL)))


->  Seq Scan on schema_registry.value_items vi1_0  (cost=0.00..734.02 rows=70 width=700)
      Output: vi1_0.id, vi1_0.serial_id, vi1_0.version, vi1_0.created_at, vi1_0.last_modified_at, vi1_0.fields, vi1_0.key, vi1_0.type, vi1_0.status, vi1_0.description, vi1_0.translation, vi1_0.group_key, vi1_0.language, vi1_0.translation_extended
      Filter: (((NOT vi1_0.deleted) OR (vi1_0.deleted IS NULL)) AND ((vi1_0.key)::text ~~ like_escape(($17)::text, ''::text)) AND (((vi1_0.language)::text = ($18)::text) OR ((vi1_0.language)::text = ($19)::text) OR (vi1_0.language IS NULL)))
```

I suspect the estimation of row count for the custom plan (above) is more realistic (probaly due to skew data in some predicate). The row count for generic plan is underestimated which leads to differencies in the plans and to lower final costs.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your answer. I guess it is the right way, but there's still question: why DB calculate this query with better cost.

Comment: You'd have to dig in the plan differencies @PoweR, I added some hints;)